# How to get object properties from IEnumerable<object[]> using LINQ- c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have one List with collection of object arrays.I am using following code to collect all EmployeeIDs

```
List<string> employeeIds= new List<string>();
var employeeFields = employees.Items.Select(c => c.EmployeeFields ).ToList();
foreach(var objectArray in employeeFields )
{
    foreach(var item in objectArray)
    {
        if(item is EmployeeID)
        {
            employeeIds.Add(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}

 public partial class EmployeeId 
  { private string itemField; /// <remarks/>           
    public string Item { get { 
  return this.itemField; } 
  set { this.itemField = value; }
 }
```

}

Here EmployeeFields consist of an object array.How can i do this in single linq query
Live Example http://rextester.com/VJB79010

Comment: What is `EmployeeID`, a class? Why do you store an `Object[]` at all instead of using a generic collection type? It seems as if the `Object[]` should be a single custom class with meaningful properties instead.

Comment: EmployeeID is Class.It has one string propert "Item"

Comment: EmployeeID is a class

Comment: And does it override `ToString()`? (As noted in answer comments, it would have been a lot easier to help you if you'd provided a [mcve] so we didn't need to ask all these questions.)

Comment: This is *still* not a [mcve], and the code you've provided calling `ToString()` does *not* do what you want. (The second piece of code is also terribly formatted, as if you don't care at all how readable it is.)  You've asked nearly 100 questions on Stack Overflow now - *please* put more effort into asking good ones. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var employeeIds = employees.Items
                     .SelectMany(e => e.EmployeeFields )
                     .OfType<EmployeeID>()
                     .Select(f => f.Item)
                     .ToList();
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/ZINFJN75313

---

edit: Updated class to contain `Item` property instead of using `ToString`

Comment: @vmb your update to my example removes the override on the various fields - which means they use the default implementation of `ToString` which just outputs the class name. Have a look again at my example where I override `ToString`

Comment: i can't able to do it in that way.its generated based on a xsd

Comment: @vmb Then how *do* you get the value of `EmployeeID` from an instance of the class? I was only copying your original code which uses `ToString`. If you're unsure, perhaps include the definition of `EmployeeID` class (if its not too long)

Comment: public partial class EmployeeId
    {

        private string itemField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Data")]
        public string Item
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114827/discussion-between-jamiec-and-vmb).

Answer (score 7):

You can use `SelectMany` and `OfType` to do this in one go:

```
var employeeIds = employees.Items
    .Select(c => c.EmployeeFields)     // Select the fields per employee
    .SelectMany(fields => fields)      // Flatten to a single sequence of fields
    .OfType<EmployeeID>()              // Filter to only EmployeeID fields
    .Select(id => id.Item)             // Convert to strings
    .ToList();                         // Materialize as a list
```

Or slightly fewer lines of code, but perhaps more tricky to understand:

```
var employeeIds = employees.Items
    .SelectMany(c => c.EmployeeFields) // Select the fields per employee and flatten
    .OfType<EmployeeID>()              // Filter to only EmployeeID fields
    .Select(id => id.Item)             // Convert to strings
    .ToList();                         // Materialize as a list
```

Comment: Why it using SelectMany(fields => fields)  ?? i getting error in this line

Comment: @vmb: It will convert an `IEnumerable<object[]>` to an `IEnumerable<object>` by flattening the sequence. But as we're using `SelectMany` for the first part, we don't need it separately. (If you'd provided a [mcve] of course, I could have ensured that my answer would work.)

Comment: @vmb: I'm not sure why you added that comment - that much was clear. But it's worth reading the [mcve] page so that next time you ask a question you can make it a better one.

Comment: When i tried this,i getteing a string list with one element,which is "EmployeeID"

Comment: @vmb: Well that sounds like your `EmployeeID` class doesn't override `ToString()`, which means the code in your question wouldn't work either. Rather than provide an example somewhere else, *please* update your question to give all the relevant information.

Comment: Thank u so much Jon